# How to Insert a int value to a linkedlist retaining the sorting?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

How to insert a value to a linked list retaining the sorting,
For example:

The values [5, 3, 1, 2, 4] comes in this order [  4 -->  2 -->  1 -->  3 -->  5 ].

I would like to come in this order. [5, 3, 1, 2, 4] in the linkedlist

This is what I tried so far, but it comes in reverse order as I mentioned above
The method gets a int value and not a int []

```
public void insert(int value) {
    
    ListNode node = new ListNode(value);

    if (node.next != null()) {
        node.next = headNode;
        headNode = node;
    } else {
        headNode = node;
    }

}
```

That's the top of the list

```
public static class ListNode {
    // der Wert dieses Knotens
    public int value;

    // Zeiger auf den Nachfolger
    public ListNode next;

    public ListNode(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
```

Comment: `if (node.next != null()) {`, I assume you mean `null` and not `null()` here but the question is what the constructor of ListNode does, isn't a `next` for a new node always null? Shouldn't you look at the last node of the list in that `if` clause instead of the newly created node?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson could you please show me how

Comment: You need to loop through the existing nodes until you find the last one (the one with next == null) and then append your new node. There must be hundreds of examples on how to do this online, [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-a-linked-list-in-java-using-class/) is one

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by looping through the existing nodes until find the last one

```
if (headNode == null) {
            headNode = node;
        } else {
            // Else traverse till the last node
            // and insert the new_node there
            ListNode last = headNode;
            while (last.next != null) {
                last = last.next;
            }

            // Insert the new_node at last node
            last.next = node;
        }
```